# Unable to toggle labels visibility in MS Access after update event

Tags: vba, ms-access

I currently have a an after update event that cycles through the textboxes in a form and toggles their visibility on if they are numbered below a certain threshold number.

```
Dim i As Long    
        Dim iMin As Long    
        Dim iMax As Long    
        iMin = 1   
        iMax = Me.txtMeasure.Value   
        With Me   
            For i = iMin To iMax   
                              .Controls("V" & i).Visible = True   
            Next i   
        End With
```

The textboxes are named `V1, V2, V3...V110`, etc." while the labels corresponding to each textbox are labeled `lblV1`, `lblV2`, `lblV3`, `lblV110`, etc." The textboxes and labels are defaulted to be invisible while the after update event toggles their visibility on. The code works for the textboxes but fails to work for the labels. I have noticed that the while the labels don't appear visible, switching to design view and then back to form view, the labels suddenly appear visible. Is there a way to debug this so that they both appear visible at the same time?

Comment: where is the code which set labels visible?

Comment: I am new to access, this code was provided to me via another stackflow user. I thought that since the textboxes and the labels are named V1 and lblV1, then the code would adjust both.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510238/cycling-through-textboxes-on-form-in-ms-access

Comment: If the labels are attached to their textboxes, they should automatically be set visible/invisible with their parent textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , it loops through controls and if it is a `textbox` or `label` you can do what you want with them, I have set them to `Visible` in this code.

```
Dim con As Control
Dim i As Long
Dim iMin As Long
Dim iMax As Long
Dim textBoxArr
Dim j As Long
        iMin = 1
        iMax = Me.txtMeasure.Value
     textBoxArr = Array("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7")
    For Each con In Me.Controls    
        If TypeName(con) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(con) = "Label" Then
          For j = 0 To UBound(textBoxArr)
            If con.Name = textBoxArr(j) Or con.Name = "lbl" & textBoxArr(j) Then
                con.Visible = True: Exit For
            End If
          Next j
        End If
    Next con
```

Comment: This makes visible all 110 textboxes and labels. I need to only make visible as many textboxes as "Me.txtMeasure.Value" indicates (hence the original with loop).

Comment: I can't do that for you. You will need to test each `control` inside the `if` statement and filter out the ones you want visible etc. If you don't know how to do that ,get back to me.

Comment: OK, I updated the code to at least test for the `textbox` and the `Label`. You will have to adjust the code to suit the names of your controls.

Answer (score 0):

You were able to add only one row to your code.

```
        Dim i As Long    
        Dim iMin As Long    
        Dim iMax As Long    
        iMin = 1   
        iMax = Me.txtMeasure.Value   
        With Me   
            For i = iMin To iMax   
                              .Controls("V" & i).Visible = True  
                              .Controls("lbl" & i).Visible = True 
            Next i   
        End With
```